# What would a spaceship look like if our design aesthetic had not changed since 1890?

Tags: space-travel, spaceships

I am struggling to visualize the space battleships of a human civilization which made it into space in the mid 1800s and have progressed to a level of technological development similar to that depicted in Star Wars.

I have decided that the ships would have a layout similar to that of the iconic Imperial class Star Destroyer;
[image]

Combined with the rather unique complexity of the French 1880s pre-Dreadnought battleship aesthetic;
[image]
[image]

A bit odd I know, but any help would be greatly appreciated. A simple sketch would be more than adequate, it would simply act as a starting point from which I can then build upon.
Funnels can be ignored.

Comment: You cannot seriously ask how would purely magical space battleships built by a civilization with a technological level similar to a fairy tale look like *"if our design aesthetic had not changed since 1890"*, without telling who is "us" whose 1890s design aesthetic you are enamored with. Late Qing Empire? Western European and American Art Nouveau? Late Victorian Neo-Classicism? Late Ottoman fascination with Neo-Gothic shapes? Late Russian imperial blend of traditional motifs with the oh so modern glass-on-steel-frameworks typical of late Victorian railway cathedrals?

Comment: in addition of what was said in the answer by tom, i think the overall look of the ship may had been a little sunder on the outside. but it would be very asunder on the inside

Comment: Honestly I don't notice much of a difference, apart from whatever the little white vertical things are.  One of your ships has round towers and one has flat facets, and that seems as big an aesthetic difference as anything there.

Comment: The picture of the Imp SD gives a shape but provides zero information about the layout except to people who have seen the movies and (probably) read the books.  There are engines at the back (not shown), a landing bay underneath (not shown), a big vulnerable bridge structure with dome-shaped shield generators on top (not identified) and turbolaser emplacements everywhere (not distinguishable). Is that what you mean by the layout?  Much more detail required before this can be answered.

Comment: Google "steampunk spaceship" for some ideas.

Answer (score 4):

### Form follows function

The design of our spaceships is mostly determined by the functional requirements of our vessels, not by aesthetic concerns.

- Our spaceships are shaped like bullets because that shape is aerodynamic.
- Our spaceships are white because white reflects sunlight instead of absorbing it (which would heat up the interior of the ship -- disposing of waste heat is a challenge in the vacuum of space). Also, possibly, because white objects are easier for astronauts to spot against the blackness of space.
- Our space vessels are compact because every extra pound/kilogram of mass requires extra fuel to launch into space, and because it would create aerodynamic drag if they had all kinds of pointed or blocky shapes sticking out of them (like a Star Destroyer does).
- The space shuttle has wings because wings are the best way to generate aerodynamic lift when your motive power is a chemical rocket.

Aerodynamic drag is not a problem for a vessel that never enters an atmosphere, but humans have not yet reached the point where we build vessels *in* space intended for exclusively non-atmospheric travel.

So, our space vessels would probably look pretty much the same no matter what our design aesthetic was, because the physics and engineering priorities would necessarily be unchanged.

The appearance of our vessels will be completely dictated by functional requirements until our technology advances to the point that launching a vessel into space becomes very, very easy. So: if we develop anti-gravity, or build a working space elevator, *then* we may be able to afford the luxury of letting our artistic sensibilities inform the design of our space vessels.

Comment: Our spacecraft are most definitely **not** "shaped like bullets". Not [even a little bit](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:View_of_the_ISS_taken_during_Crew-2_flyaround_(ISS066-E-081311).jpg). You are probably thinking about the rockets that we use to carry our spacecraft into space. (Look at any of the many SpaceX missions; the bullet-ish fairing comes off as soon as possible.) (The only exceptions are those spacecraft, such as the SpaceX Dragon, which are designed to come back down to Earth, and need to re-enter the atmosphere; they do sort-of look like particularly stubby bullets.)

Comment: I would argue that the ISS is not a "spaceship," properly so-called, because its purpose is not to travel between points. Unless I'm mistaken, the final "S" stands for "Station," which is defined as "a place or building where a specified activity or service is based." If we had multiple stations and traffic between them, we might very well have non-atmospheric vessels that care little about aerodynamic drag. The ISS belongs in the same category as the Death Star, rather than with Star Destroyers.

Comment: P.S. With the exception of capsules (and the late lamented Space Shuttle) which are designed to re-enter Earth's atmosphere, spacecraft **are** designed to be operated only in space. We carry them into space atop rockets, protected by aerodynamic fairings. Once the rocket is in space, the fairings come off, the spacecraft separates from the rocket, and does what it is meant to do.

Comment: OK, so satellites don't look like bullets because reasons. But we did launch [spacecraft which were designed to "travel between points"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_missions_to_the_outer_planets), and they still don't look like bullets.

Comment: Agreed, and that is consistent with my answer. But, perhaps the reason we _think_ we're in disagreement is that it's ambiguous which real-world objects OP intents to contrast with. I propose we let it drop until and unless the question is modified to clarify those things.

Answer (score 2):

### Vintage SF

This could be a source for inspiration. There are many in Google Images, you could try to find yourself a space ship with 19th century properties.. But from the actual 19th century science fiction, you won't find baroque designs like these 1880 marine ships you show. Jules Verne is the only 19th century SF writer known. His concept of a space ship looked like a giant bullet:

Jules Verne (1828-1905)

[[image]]

https://er.jsc.nasa.gov/seh/earlysf.html

In the 20th century, a more clear image of an actual "rocket" was conceived. But there was no experience yet with actual space flight.. and these rockets looked like fragile metal constructs. Below concept is from Authentic (1929)

[image]

https://nl.pinterest.com/pin/17170042304051273/

Maybe you'll find something close in 50s science fiction.. you get space ships with giant dimensions and sometimes a very baroque design, like below from Mad Space program (1955)

[image]

https://nl.pinterest.com/pin/35747390783001516/

Some beautiful modern designs in *vintage style* can be found with Image searches for "retro sci-fi ship" and "vintage sf ship". I show two examples,

[image]

[image]

https://wallpaper-mania.com/background/sci-fi-wallpapers/retro-sci-fi/

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot that goes into this. I will get to what I'd consider practical advice later. Just need to cover the main parts first.

- Ship purpose? Is it a troop transport? the heaviest most armored and armed main spaceship line? A lighter version of that?...etc.
- Is it AI ran? Human ran? A mixture of both?
- And if it's AI ran does the AI require a huge complex to store itself? Does the rest fall into robots? Mechanical arms that are stored into the ceiling or wall?
- How do you handle gravity? Do you have gravity engines, or just something that makes gravity, or do you use centrifugal force to generate gravity...etc.
- How many crew does it house?
- Is it capable of landing on planets or purely "void" ship that is never expected to enter a planet?
- How do you orient the "guns" and how do they work?
- What is the power situation. Does the reactor require a minimum amount of 3D space around it?
- What are the economics dictating the design?
- Does it relay on energy shields alone? Armor alone? A mixture of both?
- What is the expected serving period for a crew-member? And how much is the command concerned with their life on ship life.
- Will be made in space or on a planet?

Those I feel are the major, or some of them, that will dictate like 90% of what your ships will look like.

Lets talk in some details. For example if your ship is highly advanced with AI that control most of it. It might just require a small crew of 20 people, just a number because I want an example, that monitor things and decide on the purpose of that ship. That example think of your ship as a car, with the human crew as the driver and the rest is just machines. You don't feed power to the engine manually, you don't control the brakes in more details that pressing a pedal. So. The crew is like a captain and their whole purpose is coordinate attacks with the rest of the navy as part of the overall battle plan.

This is contrasted by a ship that require a human to arm the guns, aim the guns, operate the reactor, fly the ship, control the shields...etc. Reasons could be anything from AI is prohibited because X reason or not developed to that point yet.

This is also gonna change the number of people since if you need a human to grow food, clean the mess hall, operate very gun...etc you gonna need more humans. Not just highly skilled technicians.

Along with the economics that will dictate if your crew sleep in shifts or not, I'd imagine that would be stupid for a space-ship. But also if the serving period is like 6 month it would perhaps require less amenities then if the minimum period is 2 years.

Googling Nuclear submarines crews it's not more than 200 with the average as less. Looking up air craft carriers and the number goes as big as 5000. That's a lot of difference.

Heck. Will it have docks for smaller ships? Even worse. Do you need it tens of kilometers big or just several kilometers big.

Same with your ship. If you want a general purpose ship that has soldiers + officers + crew members + technical people...etc you might find you are launching a ship with 20000 people. There are fictional works with even higher crew numbers. But if you only want people to operate the ship then you might not have to worry about soldiers.

How do you handle gravity? Is it big enough to have it's own gravity field? Is it relaying on a sort of special metal, material, science...etc to have gravity? Because there is a reason for the iconic rings for many spaceships. But if you don't have to worry about that you might as well make it as best as you like.

Can you make a sphere with guns pointing in every direction? Because for space combat, that is 3D, I'd imagine that would be useful. But if not how will you orient the guns? In fact how big are your guns? Obviously I'm using guns as a general word here, unlikely you using conventional weapons. So. Imagine if you have gun type A that is a spacehship killer type weapon, but it's huge. So. You gonna need to build around it. Much like how just about every single tank has some of the same basics. You get the body of the tank then the whole top part, turret and all that, that preferably capable of moving in a full circle. That dictates how the rest of the tank works and is designed.

Same here. Single man, probably AI if we wanna be realistic since we already have drones but we all know how science fiction works LOVES space dog fighting, operated fighters will probably follow our jet fighter rules. But your gigantic space ship might be 3 boxes on top of each other then a gun poking out one random side. In space there is no up or down.

I'm sure you get the picture now. No need to go on about every point.
But as we are done with that how does that help you?
Well. Just imagine the larger parts of that, create floor prints of your ship, draw them or make this on a pc, then add 80s style stuff to them. Nothing more.

It's unlikely that you gonna explore every inch of your ship. So. Build your bridge or command center. Get some stuff in the engine room, the armor, mess hall, private quarters. Make sure everything has 80s flavor. Then call it a day.

I'm not saying be like movies where sometimes it's impossible for those things to physically exist. But I'm saying unless you need to build every detail first and make sure you follow it. Don't bother. Just get your larger concepts drawn first and follow them.

For example if you approach the story with the following: Ships has a mixture of AI and human crew. It's a big well made ship with proper crew facilities, the crew is 1000 personal, reactor has to be 4 stores big and is located in the center of the ship, the ship is mainly assembled in space, the ship is not build to enter atmospheres, and has 2 main guns with a lot of smaller ones.

I feel that will give you enough guide lines to start building your story. Though I'd understand if you feel this is not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to be a fuddy duddy, but I have to suggest aesthetic is virtually never a consideration for war machines. Looking at war machines then and now, the best you get is paint, flags, and a mermaid on the bow. Everything else has a distinct purpose. Therefore, the question isn't of when humans went to space, but what is necessary to accomplish the vehicle's purpose efficiently.

When I look at a star destroyer I don't particularly see a sensible design, or in different terms, I can't imagine what many of those structures are supposed to do. In that respect, you have a lot of leeway here. Make it have whatever you want, but be prepared to explain what it is and why it's that particular shape. When I look at the USS Constitution I see a ship that has not a single structure that's unnecessary. These ships absolutely look amazing and intricate, but every piece has the ineffable quality that says "this is a tool, not a decoration".

Where I personally get hung up is on overall shape and large protrusions that apparently don't snap off when changing directions. Well, you can hand wave some super material, or some magic physics-breaking machine, but if you don't want to do that, then you're overall shape must be very conservative, meaning sphere or perhaps cube. It takes massive forces to move massive objects, and thus they must endure massive structural stresses. Huge pendulum-like front ends would snap at the slightest turn. Further benefits of a sphere shape is inertial rings easily fit for artificial gravity, otherwise, you'll need that magic too.